# webpack с coffee-loader дает ошибку при изменении .coffee или .js файла: Error: task completion callback called too many times at finish

Tags: gulp, webpack

Использую `webpack`, `gulp`, `coffee-loader` с `Happypack`. Появляется ошибка при изменении `.coffee` или `.js` файла: `Error: task completion callback called too many times at finish`

Часть файла `webpack.conf.js`:

```
        resolve: {
            modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
            extensions: ['.js', '.coffee', '']
        },
        module: {
            preLoaders: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader'
            }],
            loaders: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'happypack/loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.coffee$/,
                loader: 'happypack/loader?id=coffeescripts',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }].filter(loader => loader)
        },
        plugins: [
            new HappyPack({
                loaders: ['babel'],
                threads: 4,
                verbose: false,
                cache: true
            }),
            new HappyPack({
                id: 'coffeescripts',
                threads: 4,
                loaders: ['coffee-loader']
            }),
```

В `app.js` делаю `import '../scripts/script1.coffee'`;

После запуска скрипта (с `npm`) на watch все нормально. Но при любом изменении в `.coffee` файле появляется следующая ошибка:

> [16:51:56] 'scripts:watch' errored after 6.58 min [16:51:56] Error:
>   task completion callback called too many times   at finish
>   (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:15:10)   at cb
>   (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)   at
>   Watching.handler (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\tasks\scripts.js:53:4)   at
>   Watching._done (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:81:7)   at
>   Watching. (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:61:18)
>   at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:282:37)
>   at Watching. (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:58:19)
>   at C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:275:11   at
>   Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:60:69)
>   at Compiler.afterEmit (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:272:8) 
>   at Compiler. (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:267:14)
>   at C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16   at
>   done (C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:246:17)
>   at C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16   at
>   C:\Users\X\Documents\Prj\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:43:10   at
>   FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

В чем проблема, как исправить ошибку?